# determine the membership of the list

Tags: javascript

In the text field `inputAddLabel` some character is entered. When you click the `Add tag` button, the event`pushLabel ()`is triggered. However, not every symbol should be added, but only one that is contained in `listAlphabet`. That is, a check must be carried out on the belonging of the added label to the alphabet.

```js
function pushAlphabet() {
    var alph = document.getElementById("inputAddAlphabet").value;
    if(alph.length == 1){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = alph + " ";
        document.getElementById("listAlphabet").appendChild(li);

    } else { alert('error');}
}

function pushLabel() {
    var label = document.getElementById("inputAddLabel").value;
    console.log("label", label);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = label + " ";
    document.getElementById("listLabels").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
 <div class="alphabet">
   <form>
     <input id="inputAddAlphabet" type="text">
     <input type="button" value="add symbol" onclick="pushAlphabet()">
   </form>
   <ul id="listAlphabet"></ul>
</div>
<div class="labels">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="inputAddLabel">
    <input type="button" value="add label" onclick="pushLabel()">
  </form>
  <ul id="listLabels"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, and? What's the question?

Comment: @Yftach, I don`t understand how to check this condition

Comment: Have you tried? Did you encounter any problems? What are you not understanding specifically? Do you not know where to do the check? 
This site is not about writing code for other people, it's answering questions. Show some effort.

Comment: when I write here the code in which I tried to solve the problem, users write to me that my code is rave ((

Comment: Then post the code you do have and we can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the pushed symbols (`alphabet`) and use them to filter the label:

```js
var allowedLabels = [];
function pushAlphabet() {
  var alph = document.getElementById("inputAddAlphabet").value;
  allowedLabels.push(alph);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = alph + " ";
  document.getElementById("listAlphabet").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("inputAddAlphabet").value = "";
}

function pushLabel() {
  var label = document.getElementById("inputAddLabel").value;
  console.log("label", label);
  if (allowedLabels.indexOf(label) >= 0) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = label + " ";
    document.getElementById("listLabels").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("inputAddLabel").value = "";
  } else { alert('error');}
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
   <form>
     <input id="inputAddAlphabet" type="text">
     <input type="button" value="add symbol" onclick="pushAlphabet()">
   </form>
   <ul id="listAlphabet"></ul>
</div>
<div class="labels">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="inputAddLabel">
    <input type="button" value="add label" onclick="pushLabel()">
  </form>
  <ul id="listLabels"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If the label doesn`t belong to the alphabet, should display the message "error". Don`t add an empty item to the listLabels.

Comment: how the program will look if you add more than one character to the alphabet and to the label, and a word.

Comment: I don't understand, I'm using your code where you're filtering only single character symbols. My current solution allows to add multple single-character-symbols and multiple-character-labels (words).

Comment: if  remove the restriction `if(alph.length == 1) {}`, then can add a single character to the alphabet, but, for example, a word. if  to write a text field `inputAddLabel` isn`t a single character, but a word, and check for membership in the alphabet, then how will this program look?

Comment: sorry, I don't undertand you... the program will look as we want, but I don't know what you want.

Comment: it would be useful if you explain an example with the required steps and the desired output, with concrete values.

Comment: for example, `alphabet = ['abc', 'd', 'acb d' ]`. in the text field `nputAddLable` I enter the word `acb d`. This word is there in the array, so it is added to the list of `listLabels`.

Comment: In the `alphabet` and in the `listLabels`, elements that consist not of a single symbol but of several symbols can be stored.

Comment: I don't understand why there was a `if(alph.length == 1)` condition in the first place... but I updated the answer with what I'm understanding right now.

Comment: Initially you did everything right. Thank you. I just want to understand how to do it in another case.

Comment: sorry for the arrogance, do you understand the finite state machines?))))

Comment: Hehe, that's a big topic... I don't think the comments section of this answer is the proper place to discuss it.

Comment: I created a new post. if it's not difficult for you, can you look?